# How to use a list as search criteria in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get familiar with python coding and I would like to ask a little help in the following task.

I have imported two data frames from excel dfA and dfB with pandas. I would like to count the matches of each lines from dfA in dfB.
To do this I converted `dfSearch = dfA['Title'].tolist()` to pass this as a list of values to search for.

My approach is the following:

```
for i in searchDF:
    result = dfB['COL1'].count(i)
```

Then I would like to add a new column in dfA which will store the results of each line.

```
    dfA['FIND_VAL1'] = result
```

I am sorry if this task seems trivial, but I am completely new to python and rally need some help.

**Data example A:**

```
title 
plane 
house 
car
```

**Data example B:**

```
title 
aero plane 
household 
luxury cars 
house decorations
```

**Result example:**

```
title   Results    
plane     1     
house     2    
car       1
```

Comment: Have you tried inner join in pandas on those columns ?

Comment: Please provide samples of dfA and dfB along with expected output.  See this article [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1):

You could call `str.count` in a list comprehension.

```
dfA['Results'] = [dfB.title.str.count(x).sum() for x in dfA.title]
dfA

   title  Results
0  plane        1
1  house        2
2    car        1
```

---

An alternative list comprehension using Pure Python `sum` and `str.count` as [suggested by piR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984262/how-to-use-a-list-as-search-criteria-in-a-dataframe/45985568?noredirect=1#comment78931973_45985568):

```
dfA = dfA.assign(Results=[sum([x.count(y) for x in dfB.title.values.tolist()]) 
                                       for y in dfA.title.values.tolist()])
dfA
   title  Results
0  plane        1
1  house        2
2    car        1
```

This one seems faster for small data, but may not scale as well.

Comment: If you're going to use comprehension, don't stop half-way `dfA.assign(Results=[sum([x.count(y) for x in dfB.title.values.tolist()]) for y in dfA.title.values.tolist()])` This is quicker.

Comment: @piRSquared Are you sure it scales for larger data?

Comment: Haven't done that test yet.  But your solution's time complexity is the same.  Both scale quadratically.  As does mine!  I don't know a way around that.  `O(nxm)`  But the comprehension is quicker over small data than `str.count().sum()`.

Comment: @piRSquared The annoying thing is you'd have to look for substring matches too. Otherwise you could've used a `collections.Counter` and done this in linear time.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I have tested your solution and I run into error: multiple repeat at position 23 
Why did I got an erro?

Comment: @simpleMan I don't know. I can't tell from the one sentence you've given me. Update your pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `count` `ufunc` from `numpy.core.defchararray` with some `numpy` broadcasting magic.

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import count

b = dfB.title.values.astype(str)
a = dfA.title.values[:, None]
dfA.assign(Results=count(b, a).sum(1))

   title  Results
0  plane        1
1  house        2
2    car        1
```

---

**Setup**

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame(dict(title=['plane', 'house', 'car']))

dfB = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    title=['aero plane', 'household', 'luxury cars', 'house decorations']
))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first try merging the dataframes:

```
df = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, on = "title")
```